# SQL View returns null on a EF not null field

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, nullable

I am using .NET 4.5.2, EF6 and SQL2016. I have a sql view that pulls event information

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vVisitEvent]
AS
SELECT
ev.[GUID] as EventID,
vt.[GUID] as VisitorID,
cr.Name as CountryName
FROM [Event] ev
  INNER JOIN (
  [Location] lc 
  LEFT JOIN [Country] cr ON lc.CountryGUID = cr.GUID
) ON ev.LocationGUID = lc.GUID
```

The vVisitEvent.cs under DataModel.tt is like this:

```
public string CountryName{get;set;}
```

Some locations do not have a CountryGUID so CountryName field would be null. I used LEFT JOIN and it ran properly in SQL studio. It returned all events with CountryName null if the event location has no CountryGUID. However, I got the following error in Visual Studio and it seems to be caused by the null CountryName:

```
   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey.AddHashValue(Int32 hashCode, Object keyValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.TryGetEntityEntry(EntityKey key, EntityEntry& entry)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FindEntityEntry(EntityKey key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Any ideas or possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to be related to mapping to the view. Did you specify the `[Key]` for at least one column of the entity? If this is database first, key information is not available (as opposed to mapping to a table which defines a PK).

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Entities or execute custom Sql Query? If you are using custom Sql to retrieve data, in my opinion, it is the mapping issue.

Comment: Does the view return unique rows and, if so, which field or combination of fields is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. It is db first and when vVisitEvent is added to edmx (update from database) somehow EF thinks CountryName is a DB Key and put it under `<key>` I had to manually uncheck 'db key' in edmx diagram